# Periodic wifi connectivity loss

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, dell-xps, crunchbang

I have a new Dell XPS 14 running Debian (Wheezy via Crunchbang). I've been experiencing periodic internet connectivity loss (roughly a couple minutes of downtime every 15 or so minutes, after which the system returns to normal) on wifi. This is experienced in interaction with my school's network (it's a big, serious system so it's both not something I can control and something that ought to be correctly configured). Some smaller networks have seemed to behave better, but that's a rough estimate.

I have tried changing the power management operation of my wifi card, as well as the ipV6 settings of the connection, but neither seem to help.

The chipset is an Atheros AR9462.

Comment: I assume you are using the most current drives possible for the chipset in question?  Have other versions of Linux had this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly enough, I think it was a driver issue. Installed `firmware-atheros` from debian backports and the issue hasn't reoccurred so far.

Thanks for the help, folks.

======EDIT======

The updated drivers may have helped reduce the frequency of the issue, but certainly did not solve it.

I have since upgraded my kernel from 3.2 to 3.12 and have not experienced the problem since. I propose upgrading the kernel as the best solution to this problem, perhaps in conjunction with installing the updated drivers.

Answer (score 0):

ive had the same problem. I thought it was my system though. Turns out my microwave was actially interfering with it some how. try to assign the network card to a spicific channel(if possible). another option is to change the ghz. it should be set at 2.4 by defult but you should be able to change it to 5. that will work for sure but the only problem is very few networks will work with 5ghz and you have to change your router to that to. if you got desperate you could by another network card and install it.

hope this helps somewhat, Hunter

Comment: Interesting...sounds like a difficult issue to debug, I'm glad you figured it out. Not my issue in this case, but thanks for the heads up about the potential for that issue.